# WPF listview display converter

Tags: wpf, listview, itemscontrol

I have a collection of objects that derive from a Person class and I want to bind this collection to the ItemsSource of a ListView.

I want to specify a string to display in the ListView Items. This string will be a composite of properties found on the derived classes.

I also want to bind the SelectedItem of the ListView to a property of type Person in my view model.

As far as I see it I need a string converter for my display string but I'm unsure how to bind to the items within the ItemsSource to generate the composite display string.

Can anyone give me a pointer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either overwrite the `ToString()` method of your derived classes to return your composite display string, or you can create a `Converter` like you are suggesting and pass it the entire Item. The converter would then check that the item is of a specified type, and if so compose a string of whatever properties you want.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing (overriding ToString()) so thank-you. As for passing a converter the entire item, do you mean looping through the collection's items in the converter and constructing my display string there?

Comment: @obaylis I was referring to using a `DataTemplate` like Anvarbek suggested, and having your DataTemplate be something like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PersonToDisplayStringConverter}}" />`. This will pass each Person in your ListView to the Converter to determine what the display string will be as needed.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need the StringConverter, you need [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

using DataTemplate, you can choose how you would like to display you data as an item in your listBox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did use this approach initially but it seems  a bit overkill when each item is going to be essentially the same apart from a different display string.

Answer (score 1):

If you could consider your derived class a ViewModel then you could just add a property to that class and then display it in the ListView ItemTemplate. Or like Rachel suggested override your ToString Method and then in your display binding simply write `"{Binding}"` which will force WPF to call the `ToString` method

e.g.

```
public class DerivedPerson : Person
{
  public string DisplayString 
  {
    get 
    {
      return string.Format("{0} {1}",FirstName,LastName);
    }
  }  
}
```

And you xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text={Binding DisplayString}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```